# CrudRepository save function updating deleted entities

Tags: spring-boot, crud

I am using the Spring Boot with Spring JPA and CrudRepository and I am wondering if there is any way the save function could detect deleted nested entities and update that as deleted or do I have to call the delete function on every deleted nested item.

Let's say I have this:

```
user: {
    name: 'John Smith',
    profile: {
        experience: [
            {
                job: 'Google',
                role: 'System admin'
            },
            {
                job: 'Apple',
                role: 'Platform manager'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, in my code as it is now if I change the name and add an experience and then hit the save button the CrudRepository's save function solves that just by saving the user object since I have all my items connected with the annotations @oneToOne, @oneToMany and @manyToOne.

My question is, what if I change the name, add an experience AND remove another experience? The save function in CrudRepository does not consider entities that are deleted within the object coming from frontend as DTO converted to JPA.

I want my users to be able to edit their profile page as much as they want, meaning: changing states, adding items or removing items. THEN hit the save button and the user object will be save as the new edited user object.

I hope this is making any sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make a separate restful endpoint for managing the experience entries:

- `POST /users/1/experiences` - create new experience entry
- `DELETE /users/1/experiences/1` - remove an experience entry from user
- `PUT/PATCH/POST(whatever you want) /users/1/experiences/1` - update an experience entry

Either you manage it like that or if you want to stick with what you have every time a user is saved you should remove all their experience entries from the database and replace with the fresh data from your DTOs. Will make your life much easier.